# How do you suggest a question goes to a new community?

Tags: feature-request, bug

The question *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37614673/how-to-calculate-the-area-of-a-generic-polygon* belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com/, and I wanted to vote saying it belongs on another Stack Exchange site.

However, when I went through the typical vote to close with that reason I had a selection of four Stack Exchange sites that were not what I wanted, and no way to "type ahead" to bring up the one that does belong.

The screen I was presented was:

[image]

Surely there has to be a way to fill in one of the other 50+ Stack Exchange sites not listed. Or am I missing something?